# How do I make Firefox show the most visited sites when opening a new window?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

When I start Firefox, or I open a new window, I get shown the default home screen, like this:

[image: Firefox home screen]

How do I set it to the much more useful list of most visited sites, which shows up when I open a new tab, and looks like this?

[image: Firefox new tab screen]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://support.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/gallery/images/2012-05-16-12-03-51-62e80c.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Go to Edit > Preferences, and set your home page to `about:newtab`.